# SQL - Returning unique row based on criteria and a priority

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data table that looks in practice like this:

```
Team          Shirt Number     Name
1                 1            Seaman
1                 13           Lucas
2                 1            Bosnic
2                 14           Schmidt
2                 23           Woods
3                 13           Tubilandu
3                 14           Lev
3                 15           Martin
```

I want to remove duplicates of team by the following logic - if there is a "1" shirt number, use that. If not, look for a 13. If not look for 14 then any.

I realise it is probably quite basic but I don't seem to be making any progress with case statements. I know it's something with sub-queries and case statements but I'm struggling and any help gratefully received!

Using SSMS.

Comment: What's the database engine? Oracle, PostgreSQL, DB2, etc.

Comment: SSMS - new to this. :)

Comment: Not entirely clear--- would (say) the "1" shirt be the shirt to be deleted, or would it be the shirt to *keep* while deleting all other possible duplicates?

Comment: To keep. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specified any `DBMS`, let me assume `row_number()` would work for that :

```
DELETE 
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Team  
                                ORDER BY (CASE WHEN Shirt_Number = 1
                                               THEN 1 
                                               WHEN Shirt_Number = 13
                                               THEN 2
                                               WHEN Shirt_Number = 14
                                               THEN 3
                                               ELSE 4
                                          END)
                               ) AS Seq
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE Seq = 1;
```

This assuming `Shirt_Number`s have a gap else only `order by Shirt_Number` enough.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for a `partition by` clause usage. Solution below worked in Sql Server.

```
create table #eray
(team int, shirtnumber int, name varchar(200))

insert into #eray values
(1,               1,            'Seaman'),
(1,              13,            'Lucas'),
(2,               1,            'Bosnic'),
(2,              14,            'Schmidt')

;with cte as (
   Select Team, ShirtNumber, Name, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Team ORDER BY ShirtNumber ASC) AS rn
   From #eray 
   where ShirtNumber in (1,13,14)
)
select * from cte where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table of teams, you can use `cross apply`:

```
select ts.*
from teams t cross apply
     (select top (1) ts.*
      from teamshirts ts
      where ts.team = t.team
      order by (case shirt_number when 1 then 1 when 13 then 2 when 14 then 3 else 4 end)
     ) ts;
```

If you have no numbers between 2 and 12, you can simplify this to:

```
select ts.*
from teams t cross apply
     (select top (1) ts.*
      from teamshirts ts
      where ts.team = t.team
      order by shirt_number
     ) ts;
```